# R: Function slow only when called inside a for loop

Tags: r, performance, loops, benchmarking, memoization

I have a function for finding the word-level edit distance of two sentences (full function at the end).

```
levenshtein(c("How", "do", "you", "do"), c("What", "do", "you", "do"))
## [1] 1
```

I have sets of many sentences and am computing the total edit distance for all sentence-pairs in the sets.

```
total <- 0
curr <- 0
n <- length(sentences)
for (i in (1:n)) {
    for (j in (i + 1:n)) {
      if (j > n) break
      curr <- levenshtein(sentences[[i]], sentences[[j]])
      total <- levenshtein.total + curr
    }
  }
```

This is *very* slow, but not in a way I know how to deal with:

- Benchmarking levenshtein() **during** the for loop shows some calls taking up to **two minutes**.
- Benchmarking the same calls (same sentence pairs) in the **console** results in the call taking **a second**.

---

I am not very experienced in the specifics of R, so I hope to be missing something obvious.  Unfortunately, I can not provide any specific sentence sets for privacy reasons. All sets contain around 100 sentences of lengths 1-100.

Thank you for any thoughts you might have on this issue or general thoughts on my SO usage. First post.

---

Word-level Levenshtein function :

```
levenshtein <- local({
  memo <- list()
  f <- function(sentence1, sentence2, len1=NULL, len2=NULL, offset1=0, offset2=0) {
    if (is.null(len1)) len1 <- length(sentence1)
    if (is.null(len2)) len2 <- length(sentence2)
    
    key <- paste(c(toString(offset1), toString(len1), toString(offset2), toString(len2)), collapse = ",")
  
    if (!is.null(memo[[key]])) return(memo[[key]])
    
    if (len1 == 0) return(len2)
    if (len2 == 0) return(len1)
    
    cost <- 0
    if (sentence1[[offset1 + 1]] != sentence2[[offset2 + 1]]) cost <- 1
  
    dist <- min(
      levenshtein(sentence1, sentence2, len1 - 1, len2, offset1 + 1, offset2) + 1,
      levenshtein(sentence1, sentence2, len1, len2 - 1, offset1, offset2 + 1) + 1,
      levenshtein(sentence1, sentence2, len1 - 1, len2 - 1, offset1 + 1, offset2 + 1) + cost
    )
    memo[key] <<- dist
    return(dist)
}})
```

Comment: One of the largest contributors to slow loops in R (and some extent all programming languages) is growing an existing object. This is especially bad for R, as it involves making a copy of your object every time you add an element. I am too lazy at the moment to read your levenstein function in detail, but it looks like `memo[key] <<- dist` is committing this "cardinal sin." Usually, it's better too loop with `sapply` or `lapply` which can return objects more gracefully with less memory usage (not relying on `<<-`).

Comment: @lmo, do growing `list`s really do that, too? For instance, `out <- list(iris,iris); tracemem(out[[1]]); for (i in 1:100) out <- c(out, list(iris[3:4,]))` does not trigger a memory-change of `out` (the first `iris`, suggesting that the data itself is not copied. I agree that growing objects *can* be bad and `lapply` is usually a good if not better approach, I don't think the memoization of this functions `memo` to be a performance bottleneck.

Comment: Similarly, without going too deeply into your `levenshtein` function, I'd think the recursion could be an issue. R is not tail-recursion efficient, so the deeper it goes, the more memory each function call takes on the stack.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts. Indeed, the memory usage of the routine is steady.

Would the inefficiency of the tail-recursion be consistent with the same calls being fast outside of the for loops?

For example levenshtein(Long_Sentence, Longer_Sentence) will still be moderately fast if I just call it directly, but around 100 times slower if called from within the loops.

Answer (score 0):

**Tentative solution**

Manually assigning an empty list to the memoization variable after each function call makes the routine around 40 times faster. See last line in the inside loop.

```
total <- 0
curr <- 0
n <- length(sentences)
for (i in (1:n)) {
    for (j in (i + 1:n)) {
      if (j > n) break
      curr <- levenshtein(sentences[[i]], sentences[[j]])
      total <- levenshtein.total + curr
      assign("memo", list(), envir = environment(levenshtein))
    }
  }
```

I don't know how much of a bandaid for a fundamentally overlooked problem this is, but I figure it's better than not sharing it. And if anybody has a good grasp of what's going on, or a non meta programming R-way of doing this, I'd love to learn.